# GestureDetector: how to distinguish between single touch and multi-touch gestures?

Tags: flutter

My goal is to build a widget that allows to draw using single finger tap, and scale/move the canvas when in two-fingers mode.

At the moment I had built a [ZoomView](https://github.com/skyjur/twoodtranslations/blob/master/lib/ZoomView.dart) and [DrawingOverlay](https://github.com/skyjur/twoodtranslations/blob/master/lib/DrawingOverlay.dart) widgets. `ZoomView` allows to scale and move the child passed as parameter. And `DrawingOverlay` allows to draw on top of the `child` widget passed as parameter. Right now they work well separately.

```
class ZoomView {
   build() {
     return GestureDetector(
         onScaleUpdate: () { ... }
         ...
     )
   }
}

class DrawingOverlay {
   build() {
      return GestureDetector(
         onPanUpdate: () { ... }
         ...
      )
   }
}
```

However when they are used together, things break apart:

```
build() {
    ZoomView(
      child: DrawingOverlay(
        child: ... 
      )
    )
}
```

Priority feels largely by chance. Sometimes it's starts drawing when 2 fingers are pressed and sometimes it's moving the screen with one finger while sometimes the other way round.

I would like to limit `ZoomView` to 2 finger gestures only and `DrawingOverlay` to 1 finger gestures only.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? I have similar issue with a combination of PhotoView and DismissiblePage

Comment: @Leo this was just a prototype project that I never worked beyond it so I don't know how good/bad this solution that I took would be in production setting. The particular issue I solved by implementing custom gesture recognizer to do zoom in/out/move that is active only when 2 touch points are on screen.
https://github.com/skyjur/cuisine-vocabulary-app/blob/master/lib/screens/ocr_explorer/gestures/TwoPointScaleRecognizer.dart

Comment: We decided to postpone feature connected with DismissiblePage due to it's conflict with PhotoView and other ways to have to implement zoom on  image that we tried

Answer (score -1):

It should work setting both the listeners on the same `GestureDetector`.

Comment: That is not possible, it throws error: `Having both a pan gesture recognizer and a scale gesture recognizer is redundant; scale is a superset of pan`